# local variable scope in java

Tags: java, variables, scope

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>         String a;
>         while (true) {
>             a = "bb";
>         }
>     }
> ```

the second iterator in loop variable ***a*** should have value *bb*, right? But when I'm using evaluate expression in Idea, it prompt "Cannot find local variable 'a'".

AND then I assign null to variable ***a*** when declare, a does have value in the second loop.

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>         String a = null;
>         while (true) {
>             a = "bb";
>         }
>     }
> ```

So strange, I think it's not IDEA's bug. And I guess it maybe related to the memory allocate in stack..

Comment: Sounds like compiler optimization to me. javac might see `a` as unitialized, and fail to recognize while(true) as always executed (or conversely, recognize the app will never leave that effectively no-op block anyway). What if you replace it with if(true) and put something *after* the block, put the breakpoint there and recall through evaluation window?

Comment: It is a bug in IDEA's "evaluate expression" functionality.  The Java code is valid in both examples. If you compile using `javac` and then run them, they will both behave as expected; i.e. an infinite loop.

Comment: @Martheen I think it's not a compiler optimization, because even if I add a condition to break this while loop and use variable a outside the while, a still can not evaluate in IDEA before assign when the second time iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, a does have value "bb" in my compiler. No error is reported.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a;
    while (true) {
        a = "bb";
        System.out.println(a);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Output:

> bb
>
> bb
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Then I debug with IDEA, I find the execution sequence is as follows:

1. a = "bb";
2. System.out.println(a);
3. System.out.println(a);

When a new object is created in java, the constructor helps initialize the member variable, therefore, no error is reported.